# How to wrap it up?

Tags: haskell

I have following code snippet from the haskellbook that shows step by step, how monad transformer is going to unwrap:

```
module OuterInner where

  import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
  import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
  import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader

  -- We only need to use return once
  -- because it's one big Monad
  embedded :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
  embedded = return 1

  maybeUnwrap :: ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO) (Maybe Int)
  maybeUnwrap = runMaybeT embedded

  -- Next
  eitherUnwrap :: ReaderT () IO (Either String (Maybe Int))
  eitherUnwrap = runExceptT maybeUnwrap

  -- Lastly
  readerUnwrap :: () -> IO (Either String (Maybe Int))
  readerUnwrap = runReaderT eitherUnwrap
```

There is an exercise, that I have to wrap everything again:

```
embedded :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
embedded = ??? (const (Right (Just 1)))
```

I tried as follows:

```
embedded' :: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
embedded' = MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1)))))
```

but the compiler complains:

```
D:\haskell\chapter26\src\OuterInner.hs:24:15: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Either a0' with `IO'
      Expected type: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () IO)) Int
        Actual type: MaybeT (ExceptT String (ReaderT () (Either a0))) Int
    * In the expression:
        MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1)))))
      In an equation for embedded':
          embedded' = MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1)))))

D:\haskell\chapter26\src\OuterInner.hs:24:32: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Maybe Integer'
                     with `Either String (Maybe Int)'
      Expected type: ReaderT () (Either a0) (Either String (Maybe Int))
        Actual type: ReaderT () (Either a0) (Maybe Integer)
    * In the first argument of `ExceptT', namely
        `(ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1))))'
      In the first argument of `MaybeT', namely
        `(ExceptT (ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1)))))'
      In the expression:
        MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (Right (Just 1)))))
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

How to solve the exercise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GHC typed holes extension to the rescue! It lets you plumb a `_` somewhere in your expression and make GHC tell you needed type. So, let's start with

```
:t MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const _)))

<interactive>:1:33: error:
    * Found hole: _ :: m (Either e (Maybe a))
```

Now we need a value of `ReaderT () (Either e (Maybe a))`. Plumbing `_` over and over we finally arrive at value

```
embedded = MaybeT (ExceptT (ReaderT (const (return (Right (Just 1))))))
```

Comment: What does it mean `GHC typed holes extension to the rescue`?

Comment: Uhm. Well, like Chip & Dale. Comes to help you.

Comment: Place an _ anywhere in an expression. It is an invalid identifier according to the spec, so it would be an error anyway. GHC takes the liberty of inferring a type for it and prints that type before causing that error. You build up an expression and put _ wherever you’re unsure, and then you sort of plumb down and let the types write the code, in a vague sense.

Answer (score 5):

You have defined a `MaybeT (ExceptT String (Reader ())) Int`. You've missed the innermost layer, `IO`. Unlike the others, `IO` doesn't have a concrete representation, but you can of course inject pure values into it with `return` or `pure` (duh).

```
embedded' = MaybeT . ExceptT . ReaderT
           $ (pure .) . const . Right $ Just 1
```